Is $k_d(x)=\inf(\{d(x,b):b\in B\})$ uniformly continuous?

Let $d:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a metric on $\mathbb{R}.$ Let $B$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}.$ Define $k_d:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $k_d(x)=\inf(\{d(x,b):b\in B\}.$ Is $k_d$ uniformly continuous with respect to $d?$

I think I have been able to show uniform continuity if we take $d=|\text{ . }|:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R},$ the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}.$ Below is my work.
Let $\varepsilon>0.$ Suppose $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x-y|<\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$ Let $b\in B.$ Then, we have that $|y-b|-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<|x-b|<|y-b|+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$ (Is this obvious, or do we need some more justification? It is clear to me by just picturing the real line). Taking the infimum as $b$ varies along $B,$ we get $k_d(y)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}≤k_d(x)≤k_d(y)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$ This gives $|k_d(x)-k_d(y)|≤\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon.$ This proves uniform continuity.
I have two questions now. Firstly, is the above proof correct? Secondly, what does the situation look like for general $d?$ Will it be continuous? Uniformly continuous?

Your proof looks right; for clarity, use triangle equality for the step you said you pictured the real line.
